# Derivative of a matrix function with respect to an argument

Tags: matrices, functions, derivatives

I am trying to find the derivative of $U$ with respect to $N$ in the following matrix function:

$$U({\bf N}) = \frac{{\bf S}^T({\bf P}-{\bf N})}{\sqrt{({\bf P}-{\bf N})^T({\bf P}-{\bf N})}}$$

$$ \frac{dU}{d{\bf N}}=?$$

$S$,$P$ and $N$, are all 3by1 matrices (3D vectors), and the $T$ stands for the transpose of a matrix.
Do you have any idea how I can compute it? it would be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen the [Matrix Cookbook](https://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=5042097&fileOId=5042100)?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use lowercase latin for vectors and greek for scalars, i.e. $\{n,p,s,\mu\}$ instead of $\{N,P,S,U\}$

And introduce a new vector variable, $w$, of length $\lambda$
$$\eqalign{
 w &= (n-p) &\implies dw = dn\cr
 \lambda^2 &= w^Tw &\implies \lambda\,d\lambda = w^Tdw \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of these new variables, then find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 \mu &= \lambda^{-1}(s^Tw) \cr\cr
 d\mu
 &= \lambda^{-1}s^Tdw - \lambda^{-2}(d\lambda)(s^Tw) \cr
 &= \lambda^{-1}s^Tdw - \lambda^{-3}(w^Tdw)(s^Tw) \cr
 &= \lambda^{-3}\Big(\lambda^2s - (s^Tw)w\Big)^T dw \cr
 &= \lambda^{-3}\Big(\lambda^2s - (s^Tw)w\Big)^T dn \cr\cr
\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial n}
 &= \lambda^{-3}\Big(\lambda^2s-(s^Tw)w\Big) \cr
 &= \frac{(sw^T-ws^T)\,w}{(w^Tw)^{3/2}} \cr
}$$

Comment: You can also express this gradient as $$\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial n}=\frac{\lambda s-\mu w}{w^Tw}$$

Comment: Oops!  Just noticed that I defined $\mu$ as the **negative** of your function, so multiply my gradient by minus one.